# finding the slant length of a cone on a pitch

Tags: geometry

[image: cone diagram]

pardon my terrible paint drawing. My issue is finding the length of D which is the length from above the pitch angle (A) up to the pinnacle.

I'd originally gotten the rise of the angle A over the run of B and then used that point to find what I thought was the length of D but the issue is that since the angle of the slant starts from the base, it doesn't take into account the run of the slant line (D) up the point where it reaches the angle line (A).

how can I take into account the distance that the slant covers below the pitch? ie. find the point at which the slant line D bisects the pitch angle A

Comment: Not clear from your question what is known. Does your figure represent a section through a right circular cone of radius $R$ and height $H$? What's $B$ and $D$ in three dimensions? Start by describing the problem, before you describe what you have tried.

Comment: for simplicity, the problem can be considered in 2d  as a triangle on a pitch. we know everything in green, so the height of the triangle from the base, we know half the base is R. We know the angle A from which line D starts, and the length of B which is the point where line D would intersect the base

Comment: Is this a cross-section of the cone along the axis of the cone? Or some of the lines here are on the curved surface of the cone (hence "slant length" in the title)?

Comment: Assuming you have only a triangle and not a cone does make the problem simpler, but also makes the answer different from the question you asked. Consider, for example, the case where $A$ is nearly zero and $B=R.$ You will get an answer slightly less than $H$, whereas the correct answer is only slightly less than $\sqrt{H^2+R^2},$ the slant height of the entire cone. Now that you have answers for the triangle, however, you can compute the answer for the cone relatively easily if you want.

Comment: @DavidK hey you're right! I think i need an extra step to find the corresponding point of the base circumference and get the slant length from that point with D. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's solve this problem using a coordinate system at the bottom of the altitude $H$. Then the vertex of the cone is at $(0,H)$. The left most point is at $(-R,0)$, and the point at $B$ from there has coordinates $(-R+B,0)$. The equation of the line that contains $D$ is given by:
$$
\frac{y-0}{y-H}=\frac{x-(-R+B)}{x-0}$$
For the line at angle $A$ you have $$\tan A=\frac{y}{x+R}$$
Now you have two equations with two unknowns ($y$ and $x$). If you solve the system, you get the intersection of the two lines. Once you have the coordinates of the intersection, you can get the length $D$.

Answer (score 0):

Trigonometric approach: apply the sine rule to the triangle containing $D$ to obtain
\begin{align}
D=&\sqrt{H^2+R^2}\frac{\sin(\tan^{-1}\frac HR-A)}{\sin(\tan^{-1}\frac H{R-B}-A)}
=\sqrt{H^2+(R-B)^2}\cdot \frac{H-R\tan A}{H-(R-B)\tan A}
\end{align}